# sql sp year or year and month

Tags: stored-procedures, dry

I have some SP that takes year and month:

```
Create PROCEDURE Report(
    @targetYear int,
    @targetMonth int
)
```

And querying it with:

```
select sum(col) where year(dateTime) = @targetYear and month(dateTime) = @targetMonth
```

Then I have the same thing for year only

```
Create PROCEDURE Report(
    @targetYear int
)
```

and querying it like:

```
select sum(col) where year(dateTime) = @targetYear
```

Of course, the logic is more complicated than sum(col)

My question is, how can I write this SP so the logic is not repeated across the two SP, even if it means passing 0 for target month when I mean the whole year?

Answer (score 1):

I like Joel's answer except his won't work if you pass in a zero as the month. You will want @targetMonth=0 for example:

```
SELECT sum(col) 
WHERE year(dateTime) = @TargetYear AND 
(@targetMonth = 0 OR month(dateTime) = @targetMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(col) 
FROM [yourtable]
WHERE year(dateTime) = @TargetYear 
    AND (@targetMonth < 0 OR month(dateTime) = @targetMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stored proc can have an optional parameter:

```
Create PROCEDURE Report( @targetYear int, @targetMonth int = null )
```

It can be called either with the parameter or not:

```
exec Report 2009
exec Report 2009, 2
```

Then in your logic check for a null:

```
SELECT sum(col) 
FROM [yourtable]
WHERE (year(dateTime) = @TargetYear and @targetMonth = null)
  OR (year(dateTime) = @TargetYear AND @targetMonth = month(dateTime))
```

or

```
SELECT sum(col) 
FROM [yourtable]
WHERE year(dateTime) = @TargetYear 
  AND (@targetMonth = null OR year(dateTime) = @TargetYear)
```